# program to reverse string skipping some characters while printing

Tags: arrays, string, pointers

It prints the characters in reverse order just fine **except when the string is 8 characters long**.

Eg -

"**what man**" gives "**am tahw**" Why ?

whereas "what many" gives "ynam tahw" just as it should.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[100];
    char x;
    char*i = a;
    printf("Enter a message:");
    while ((x = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        *i = x;
        i++;

    }

    while (i >= &a[0])
    {
        printf("%c", *i--);
    }
    printf ("\n");



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Modification in your code:**

1. Change `printf("%c", *i--);` to `printf("%c", *--i);` in while loop.

You can improve the quality of your program as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    char *s;
    int len,i;
    clrscr();
    printf("\nENTER A STRING: ");
    gets(s);
    len=strlen(s);
    printf("\nTHE REVERSE OF THE STRING IS:");
    for(i=len;i>=0;i--)
        printf("%c",*(s+i));
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Yes well but my question was why does "what man" gives "am tahw" ? Why does it skip a character, I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: @callmeanythingyouwant because there was some logical error in your code. Check my modified answer. Let me know now it is working fine or not.

Comment: Hey, yes your solution is working. Wow. I still don't understand why though. Could you explain ?

Comment: @callmeanythingyouwant let me know where you are stuck in code, I will definitely reach out to you.